# Combine multiple python files from GitHub

Tags: python-3.x, github

I'm trying to create a Bar chart race with Python on Jupyter Notebook that looks like this one:
[image]

So I found a package called [bar_chart_race](https://github.com/dexplo/bar_chart_race) on GitHub. However, the package has no option to add images.

Fortunately, I found this forked repository https://github.com/andresberejnoi/bar_chart_race/tree/image_labels that allows adding images.

[image]

The problems is that I normally work with only 1 python file at a time on Jupyter Notebook.

From what I see, there are so many python files and when I tried to run one of them, the error:

`attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

[image]

What should I do to gather all the codes together and work on my computer?

This is my first time trying to understand how things work on GitHub.
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: The title is misleading as you're not combining code, you're trying to use a properly package set of codes. See below for how to install that code

Comment: Sorry for the misleading question. I'm quite new to GitHub. I thought that if I could combine all python files, it would be easier to use. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No worries, the title is usually the most important thing for other stackoverflow users/browsers to find it when they have the same problem.

Comment: Did the solution I provide fixed the issue?

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved. Thank you very much you made my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you received has to do with how the files are indexed. Note that this is a fully package codebase from what I can tell (there's a `setup.py`), so you should be able to install it on machine in either a virtual env or conda environment (I recommend using environments to avoid it corrupting your `base` environment of python).

After you clone the repo, you can install it

```
git clone https://github.com/andresberejnoi/bar_chart_race/
cd bar_chart_race
python setup.py install
```

I suggest these steps as this `forked` repo has not been merged into the main repo, so `pip install` will not work to capture the image feature.

Now your environment knows what and where is "bar_chart_race"

Try to open a Jupyter Notebook in the same environment and try `import bar_chart_race`. If that works, than you can work with this python package in your notebook.